# How to cleanly add an argument to a function

Tags: go

I have a function that's called quite a few times. How do I now add an additional parameter to that function without having to modify all the call-sites (essentially intruding the default value there and adding a bunch of noise) as well as keeping type safety?

All the languages I have previously used either support default arguments or overloading, so I am quite lost as to how I would do that.

Answer (score 9):

Go doesn't have default arguments, neither it has function overloading. I think, the best you can do without changing the rest of the code is:

1. Rename the function `Func()` to `FuncWithNewArg()`
2. Add a new argument to `FuncWithNewArg()`
3. Create a new function named `Func()` with the original signature. `Func()` will call `FuncWithNewArg()` passing all its argument plus the default value for the new one.

Comment: This seems like a very ugly solution.

Comment: @Philippe it's a fine solution; once you see the actual code in your editor, it won't look that bad

Comment: @blackgreen Even for languages that allow dynamic/flexible function definitions, this is often preferred, because it's explicit. The reader of your code will always know exactly what's going on.

Comment: It doesn't work for more than one additional argument.

Comment: @Philippe for more than one argument, you will have the ultimate function with all the arguments, and as many wrappers with default values as you need for more frequent use cases.

Comment: But if you have too many arguments in a function, it's a bad sign in any language.

Comment: Another option would be to have a single struct argument, and omitted fields would have zero-values, but that 1) wouldn't satisfy the constraint of not changing the existing code, 2) might be a sign that the function has too many arguments.

Comment: @bereal That's the option I ended up going with. It's still a huge diff, but it won't be the next time.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to add an optional argument to a function in Go is with a [variadic function](https://gobyexample.com/variadic-functions).  As long as your function doesn't already have any variadic variables, you can add one without requiring all the existing callers to update. However, this does change the function signature, so if you have anything depending on that signature (i.e. assigning the function to a variable), such things may break.

To illustrate, suppose your function is:

```
func Foo(count int) error {
    // do stuff
}
```

You could add an optional variadic variable at the end:

```
func Foo(count int, optional ...string) error {
    // do stuff
}
```

You then access the `optional` variable as as a slice of the designated type (`[]string` in this case).

Now `Foo()` can be called as either `Foo(3)` or `Foo(3, "bar")`.

Actually, it can be called with any number of arguments, so long as they match the type of the variadic variable.  I.e. `Foo(3, "bar", "baz", "qux")` is also valid.

A function can take only a single variadic variable, and it must be the last one. This means you can't mix and match types.  For example, this is invalid:

```golang
func Foo(count int, optional ...string, alsoOptional ...float64) error
```

If you need something more flexible than this, your best bet is to add a new function, as suggested in @bereal's answer:

```golang
func Foo(count int) error { ... }

func FooWithOther(count int, other string) error { ... }
func FooWithMany(count, int, other string, more bool) error { ... }
```